# Why does python enable assertions by default

Tags: python, assert, language-design

I have been reading a bit about the assert statements in python and other languages. 
Particularly, I've read up on the assert in Python, Java and C. *My understanding may not be a 100% correct, but the question that follows is about Python.*

**In the case of Python, why are assertions enabled by default?** Why does python do this differently from other languages?** Is there a particular reason - compile time vs interpreted - for it?

- In Java, assertions are disabled by default unless explicitly enabled.
- In C and C++, programs using assertions from `assert.h` don't have them disabled by default  but most Makefiles do define `NDEBUG` for releases/distributions.

  - CMake sets NDEBUG by default for `dist`
  - Many projects define their own `assert` Macro instead of using `assert.h` and change the default behavior.

*I know my question is asking for a bit of historical context, but that is in fact the kind of answer that I am looking for.*

***Side note:***
*I'm also new to python and where I work, we don't run **any** code in production with the optimization flags enabled. Is this a common practice when deploying python applications?*

If you're interested, then below are the sources that I've read:

- [What is the use of "assert" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142418/what-is-the-use-of-assert-in-python)
- [Why assertion is not enabled by default in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324537/why-assertion-is-not-enabled-by-default-in-java)
- [Why is assert not enabled by default in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29120928/why-is-assert-not-enabled-by-default-in-java) (duplicate)
- http://archive.is/5GfiG - Python mailing list archive on when to use assert.

Comment: To catch errors by default? Catching errors is handy.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that assertions are disabled in Java, C and C++ because of performance reasons. Asserts make the code slower and also might make some code optimizations impossible. Those languages have speed as a top priority, so it makes sense to disable them by default.

Python on the other hand is not concerned so much with speed. Have a look at the [Python Zen](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

```
Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced.
```

Assertions raise `AssertionError`, so better not pass them silently.

Answer (score 1):

> In the case of Python, why are assertions enabled by default? Why does python do this differently from other languages?** Is there a particular reason - compile time vs interpreted - for it?

Because generally speaking there's no reason not to. Python is not a fast language, and having code which looks like it should do things by default but does not is odd. Incidentally that is spreading to more language e.g. Rust has an `assert!` macro which *always runs*, and a separate `debug_assert!` which only runs in debug mode.

This property is also leveraged by the non-xunit testing packages like `pytest` which use and rewrite assertions in order to make them better (both more convenient and less constrainig) `assert*` methods.

> Side note: I'm also new to python and where I work, we don't run any code in production with the optimization flags enabled. Is this a common practice when deploying python applications?

If you're asking whether running pyhton *without* `-O` is common, then yes. `-O` does relatively little that's useful: I don't think I've ever seen a codebase using `__DEBUG__` and bypassing `assert` always feels icky. And `-OO` basically only does negative things.

The only cases I've seen which routinely use `-O` / `-OO` are:

- Windows packaging where it does look semi-frequent
- misguided attempts at obfuscation