# Why do a and b share the same address in the following code?

Tags: c++, c, char

Why does the static assert fire in this case? Are these at the same address because of 64 bit address lines and a char is a single byte?

```
  #include <type_traits>

    int main()
    {
      char a='a';
      char b='b';

      static_assert ( &a == &b, " ERROR: Same addr"  ) ;
    }
    main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
    main.cpp:9:3: error: static assertion failed:  ERROR: Same addr
```

Comment: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293588.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293588.aspx)

Comment: "assert" means "error unless (condition)", not "error if (condition)"

Comment: @bjackfly, Please don't vandalize your questions. Even though it is a duplicate, it is still a valid question which has valid answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does assert do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018683/what-does-assert-do)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a` and `b` are at different addresses. You have your assert the wrong way around. Your assert fails because the two addresses are *not* them same. Try

```
static_assert ( &a != &b, " ERROR: Same addr"  ) ;
```

Answer (score 6):

You've got the logic backwards. `static_assert` is triggered when the condition is `false`, that is, the two object don't have the same address.