# Debugging in Java with preconditions

Tags: java, preconditions, post-conditions

Working with Chromium codebase I got used to macros like `CHECK(condition);`, `DCHECK(contidtion)` and `NOTREACHED;`. They introduce assertions (usually preconditions) to the code and allow to terminate program with some info in a log, an in debug build `DCHECK` and `NOTREACHED` would also stop debugger to investigate the case. First one is active only in release mode and latter two only in debug - when "unactive" they would be replaced by an empty macro and not cause any overhead.

Is there some library in Java that allows such thing? I know that I could create some static method/object and depending on configuration swap configuration but I cannot see the way to avoid creating overhead. Besides, I wouldn't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `assert` keyword:

```
public void yourMethod(String arg) {
    assert arg != null : "arg may not be null";
    // ...
}
```

which is equivalent to

```
public void yourMethod(String arg) {
    if (arg == null) throw new AssertionError("arg may not be null");
    // ...
}
```

Asserts are disabled unless the `-ea` switch is given when starting the JVM and will have close to 0 overhead when disabled.

The equivalent to `NOTREACHED` would be `assert false;`

Related: [What does the "assert" keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018683/what-does-assert-do/3018755)

Comment: [Programming With Assertions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html#usage-control) discusses how to use this, including for pre-conditions, post-conditions, and control flow invariants.

Comment: So I need to manually handle it in my `UncauchtExceptionHandler` to log error and terminate, and configure debugger to stop on `AssertionException`? I guess it cannot be done prettier...

Comment: Debuggers often stop automatically on uncaught exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I authored [a library](https://bitbucket.org/cowwoc/requirements/) that helps writing preconditions, postconditions with an emphasis on readability. For example:

```
// Input
List<Integer> actual = Arrays.asList(2, 3, 4, 6);
List<Integer> expected = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 5);
requireThat(actual, "actual").containsAll(expected);

// Output
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: actual must contain all elements in: [1, 3, 5]
Actual : [2, 4, 6]
Missing: [1, 5]
```